# If a no-deal Brexit happens will EU provisions on reverse engineering be nullified?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property

As it stands the UK implements an EU law which prevents the reverse engineering of proprietary software with few exceptions, could this change once we leave the EU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two kinds of EU laws: regulations and directives.

- Regulations have direct effect throughout the EU, which helps harmonize the laws of the Single Market.
- Directives instruct the member states to implement their own laws to some effect, which helps adapt the laws to that member state's circumstances.

Reverse engineering is the subject of the EU [Computer Programs Directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Programs_Directive). As a directive it has no direct effect in the UK. The directive was implemented by [amending the UK's Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1992/3233/made).

The Copyright Act is UK law, created by parliament and not the EU. It will continue to be in effect even after a Brexit.

Note that many EU regulations also have corresponding passages in UK law, for example the [Data Protection Act 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_Act_2018) mirrors the GDPR. And per the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018, all relevant EU laws will be transformed into domestic UK law upon exit day, including the principle of supremacy of (ex-)EU law over domestic law. That way, the regulatory environment doesn't suddenly change. So even if reverse engineering were the subject of an EU regulation, it would continue to apply after Brexit and would supersede pre-Brexit UK laws to the contrary.

Comment: Given current events, an "orderly" Brexit would seem to be a contradiction in terms. If such a thing is going to happen, it won't be in the immediate future.

Comment: @kevin even in a hard brexit the data protection act remains in force.

Comment: Kevin. U.K. civil service has been working on the problem since July 2016. They had a deadline of March 2019. So I expect them to have replacements for all the EU regulations ready on October 31st. And these replacements will become law when  the U.K. leaves the EU, with or without a deal. It’s a purely internal British matter.

Comment: The [European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_(Withdrawal)_Act_2018) 'enables the transposition of directly-applicable already-existing EU law into UK law,[2] and so "create a new category of domestic law for the United Kingdom: retained EU law."' This will happen whatever the nature of any Brexit. After that, Parliament will be able to amend or repeal any retained EU law.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff they'll also be able to amend domestic law that formerly implemented EU directives, including the Copyright Act.  But the chance that they'll amend it to make significant changes to restrictions on reverse engineering seems quite remote indeed.  People in the UK complained about a few EU regulations, and those are probably likely to be changed, but this one wasn't among them as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @amon: do you have a source for the claim in the final paragraph that "most" EU regulations have some equivalent in UK law (assuming that's what you meant)? And on that subject, what do you mean by "pendant"?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Thank you for your comments and edits. I've included an explanation of the withdrawal act's effects. It is of course hyperbole that *most* EU regulations would be mirrored, since most regulations are just incredibly boring administrativa. What I was trying to express is that regulations still have a large effect on primary legislation. I've removed the word “pendant”. It means “counterpart” in my other language, but apparently not in English.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff EU regulations are, right now, law in the UK so there will not be anything equivalent in UK law - it would be pointless at best and contradictory at worst. Civil servants have been working to 2016 to identify regulations that could be taken word by word as UK law (about 90%) and regulations that need some changes in the wording (for example "all baby clothing sold in the EU" would need changing to "all baby clothing sold in the UK"), and create the text of UK laws to be introduced after Brexit. ...

Comment: ... So they have (or should have) the text for about 10,000 new UK laws ready, to be accepted in one huge block as UK law the second the UK leaves the EU, and all the EU regulations cease to be law.

Comment: @gnasher729 of course, they haven't been passed *yet*, and the fact that they can be accepted as one block quickly does not necessarily mean that they will. They still need to go through the proper process to become valid law - it's possible (though hopefully unlikely) that the parliament will take some time to approve these laws, or wish to debate some aspects of them, or it will not be in session and can't accept anything, and if they don't manage to complete this until October 31st for whatever reason, then that leaves a huge temporary gap.

Comment: @Peteris There are over 10,000 EU regulations. There's no chance they can be individually discussed by parliament. And there's no need to: All these regulations are law now (by being EU regulations) and you want them all to become regular UK law when Brexit happens, or you get chaos. Once Brexit is done, there's any amount of time to change whatever government isn't happy with.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly formulated:

> UK implements an EU law

which essentially means: It is a directive of the EU.

There are (at least) two kinds of EU laws to be distinguished:

- **directives** have to be implemented, that is written into national law. Member states have to pass these laws.
- **regulations** take effect immediately, without needing to be passed as national law.

The law about reverse engineering is a directive. So, it is a UK-implemented law, valid in the UK, independend from remaining in the EU.

Comment: There are differences between EU regulations and EU directives.  EU regulations have direct effect, and do not require a member state "to pass laws on its own to meet the laws of the EU."

Comment: @phoog Thanks for pointing this out. English is not my mother tongue, of course I was aware of "Richtlinien" and "Verordnungen" ;-)

Comment: You're welcome.  I've changed my vote.  In this case, since the subject of the question is a directive, the UK would be free to change its law to be incompatible with the directive after it leaves the EU (unless of course by some post-Brexit agreement it were to commit itself to honoring any directive).  I'm not aware of any suggestion that this is likely with regard to reverse engineering software, but it already underway in the area of immigration law, in the case of directive 2004/38/EC concerning freedom of movement of EU citizens and their family members.

Comment: But then "free movement" is an area that the Brexiteers mostly _want_ to change. Nobody ever said "we should leave the EU because reverse engineering isn't allowed".

Comment: I think it mostly depends on how popular the topic is. Ask 100 random people about migration, and ask them about reverse engineering. Most people won't even know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

The UK has implemented EU directives, and EU regulations are automatically law in the UK. There are preparations so that all the EU regulations, which will cease to be law in the UK the moment the UK leaves the EU, will all be replaced by equivalent UK laws at the same moment.

So apart from possibly mistakes in that process, and slightly changed wording in some of the replacement laws for EU regulations, the laws in the UK one second after Brexit will be the same as one second before Brexit.

*After* Brexit, the UK is obviously free to change any UK laws. If they want to change the laws about reverse engineering of proprietary software, then they can and probably will. If they don't want to change those laws, they won't. I haven't heard any big complaints from politicians about these laws, so they might stay unchanged for quite a while.